Llama AI API not returning response
I'm just trying to learn Llama AI API and I'm trying to get it to respond to the question "What are common questions to ask on an NDA". but I'm unable to get an response. The content field in the response json is always NULL.
I tried the example given on their website but also was not able to get a response.
const apiRequestJson = {
  "messages": [
    { "role": "user", "content": "What are the common questions to ask to create an NDA for a food industry for an employee?" }
  ],
  "functions": [
    {
      "name": "get_nda_questions",
      "description": "Get the frequently asked questions to generate an NDA contract",
      "parameters": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "Industry": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "The industry to generate this contract in"
          },
          "BusinessType": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "NDA for a business or individual"
          }
        }
      },
      "required": ["Industry", "BusinessType"]
    }
  ],
  "stream": false,
  "function_call": "get_nda_questions"
};

app.get('/contract', async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const { default: LlamaAI } = await import('llamaai');
      const llamaAPI = new LlamaAI(apiToken);
  
      // Run the first API request
      const response = await llamaAPI.run(apiRequestJson);
      const output = response['choices'][0]['message'];
      

     // Parse the function call arguments
      const funcArguments = output['function_call']['arguments'];
  
      // Create flight_info object
      const flight_info = {
        "Industry": funcArguments.Industry,
        "BusinessType": funcArguments.BusinessType
      };
  
      // Convert flight_info to a JSON string
      const stringInfo = JSON.stringify(flight_info);      
  
      // Prepare the second API request JSON
      const second_api_request_json = {
        "model": "llama-70b-chat",
        "messages": [
          {"role": "user", "content": "What are the common questions to ask to create an NDA for a food industry for an employee?"},
          {"role": "function", "name": output['function_call']['name'], "content": stringInfo}
        ],
        "functions": [
            {
              "name": "get_nda_questions",
              "description": "Get the frequently asked questions to generate an NDA contract",
              "parameters": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "Industry": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "The industry to generate this contract in"
                  },
                  "BusinessType": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "NDA for a business or individual"
                  }
                }
              },
              "required": ["Industry", "BusinessType"]
            }
          ]
      };
        
      const second_response = await llamaAPI.run(second_api_request_json);
      const second_output = second_response['choices'][0]['message']['content']; //This returns null for some reason
      
    res.send(second_response)      

    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
    }
  });


you can try making a more general request to the API and avoid giving a function call :

import LlamaAI from "llamaai";

const apiToken = process.env.LLAMA_SECRET_KEY;
const llamaAPI = new LlamaAI(apiToken);

const handleChat = async (req, res) => {

    try {
        const apiRequestJson = {
            model: "llama-13b-chat",
            messages: [{ role: "user", content: "When's the next flight from Amsterdam to New York?" }],
        };
        const response = await llamaAPI.run(apiRequestJson);

        if (response.choices[0].message.function_call) {
            const functionCall = response.choices[0].message.function_call;
            console.log(`Function to call: ${functionCall.name}`);
            console.log(`With arguments: ${JSON.stringify(functionCall.arguments)}`);
            // Esegui la logica appropriata, se possibile
        }

        res.json(response);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.json(err);
    }
};

export default { handleChat };


you should get a similar response from the API:

{
    "created": 1721993920,
    "model": "llama-13b-chat",
    "usage": {
        "prompt_tokens": 19,
        "completion_tokens": 67,
        "total_tokens": 86
    },
    "choices": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "message": {
                "role": "assistant",
                "content": "According to flight schedules, the next flight from Amsterdam (AMS) to New York (JFK) is departing at 10:00 AM (CET) on [current date]. Please note that flight schedules are subject to change, and I recommend checking with the airline or a flight search engine for the most up-to-date information.",
                "function_call": null
            },
            "finish_reason": "stop"
        }
    ]
} 


